# Al poner un div mi JavaScript deja de funcionar

Tags: javascript, html

Al poner un `div` mas específicamente `<div class ="izquierda">`, mi código `js` deja de funcionar.

Lo que debería de hacer mi función `js` es que debería mandar un mensaje de correo valido o invalido al momento de apretar el botón **verificar correo**(línea de código 60).

También revisé el `CSS` y no afecta en nada.

```js
function validarCorreo(correo) {
  var expReg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
  var esValido = expReg.test(correo);
  if (esValido == true) {
    alert('El correo electronico es valido');
  } else {
    alert('El correo no es valido');
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;"><i class="loti  fa-solid fa-user-pen" style="font-size: 25px;"></i> REGISTRO DE USUARIOS</h3>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="izquierda">
      <h4>DATOS DEL USUARIO</h4>
      <form action="registro_usuarios.php" method="POST">
        Título:
        <select id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-select" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option>Lic.</option>
          <option>Ing.</option>
          <option>Dr.</option>
          <option>Dra.</option>
          <option>Sr.</option>
          <option>Sra.</option>
        </select>
        Nombre completo:
        <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required> Fecha de nacimiento:
        <input id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" type="date" class="form-control" required> Sexo:
        <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="form-select" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option>Hombre</option>
          <option>Mujer</option>
        </select>
        Teléfono:
        <input id="telefono" name="telefono" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="2741227113" required>
    </div>
    <div class="vl"></div>
    <div class="derecha">
      <h4>USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA</h4>
      Correo:
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un correo" onblur="buscar_datos();" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon2" value="validar Correo" onclick="validarCorreo(form.correo.value)">Verificar Correo</button>
      </div>
      Contraseña:
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese al menos 8 caracteres" required> Confirmar contraseña:
      <input name="conf_password" id="conf_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repita la contraseña" required> Puesto de trabajo:
      <select name="area_trabajo" id="area_trabajo" class="form-select" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione el área</option>
        <option>Administración</option>
        <option>Admisión</option>
        <option>Archivo</option>
        <option>Contabilidad</option>
      </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script_funciones.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validarco_usuario.js"></script>
</body>
```

Mi `js` se llama **validarco_usuario.js** y esto es lo que contiene, es solo para que me me valide que los usuarios estén poniendo un correo que sea valido, este código se usa en el `<div="derecho">` pero no entiendo porque al momento de que yo pongo el `<div="izquierda">` de alguna manera afecta a el lado derecho haciendo que no llegue el `js`.

Comment: tienes el inicio de tu form dentro de izquierda y el fin de tu form dentro de derecha, eso está raro no se si este sea el problema pero form debiese ser el padre de izquierda y derecha. Dado que tienes la carga de los js al final quizás al "romper" el archivo html con etiquetas mal abiertas o cerradas, quizás puede que esto provoque el que no se carguen los archivos

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir más de tu JS? ¿Qué código es el que llama a la función `validarCorreo`? Estoy interesado en ver como obtienes el valor de `correo` que pasas a la función.

Comment: acabo de borrar el form y sigue igual

Comment: jacobo estodo el codigo js que tengo pero validarCorreo en linea 59. las lineas donde hago todo lo de que me mande un mensaje de si el correo es valido o no son de la linea  57 a 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, estás usando dos funciones:

- `onblur="buscar_datos();"`
- `onclick="validarCorreo(form.correo.value)"`

Eliminé la primera, porque en la consola se puede observar que aparece un error indicando que la función `buscar_datos()` no está definida.

Si eliminas las etiquetas `form`, también debes eliminarlo del parámetro en la función `validarCorreo(form.correo.value)` quedando de esta manera `validarCorreo(correo.value)`. O pudes dejarlo, pero saca las etiquetas `form` fuera de los `div`, *tal como te mencionó en los comentarios @lpzadquiel*

```js
function validarCorreo(correo) {
  var expReg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
  var esValido = expReg.test(correo);
  if (esValido == true) {
    alert('El correo electronico es valido');
  } else {
    alert('El correo no es valido');
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;"><i class="loti  fa-solid fa-user-pen" style="font-size: 25px;"></i> REGISTRO DE USUARIOS</h3>
  <div class="tab">
    <form action="registro_usuarios.php" method="POST">
      <div class="izquierda">
        <h4>DATOS DEL USUARIO</h4>
        Título:
        <select id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-select" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option>Lic.</option>
          <option>Ing.</option>
          <option>Dr.</option>
          <option>Dra.</option>
          <option>Sr.</option>
          <option>Sra.</option>
        </select>
        Nombre completo:
        <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required> Fecha de nacimiento:
        <input id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" type="date" class="form-control" required> Sexo:
        <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="form-select" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option>Hombre</option>
          <option>Mujer</option>
        </select>
        Teléfono:
        <input id="telefono" name="telefono" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="2741227113" required>
      </div>
      <div class="vl"></div>
      <div class="derecha">
        <h4>USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA</h4>
        Correo:
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un correo" autocomplete="off">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon2" value="validar Correo" onclick="validarCorreo(form.correo.value)">Verificar Correo</button>
        </div>
        Contraseña:
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese al menos 8 caracteres" required> Confirmar contraseña:
        <input name="conf_password" id="conf_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repita la contraseña" required> Puesto de trabajo:
        <select name="area_trabajo" id="area_trabajo" class="form-select" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Seleccione el área</option>
          <option>Administración</option>
          <option>Admisión</option>
          <option>Archivo</option>
          <option>Contabilidad</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script_funciones.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validarco_usuario.js"></script>
</body>
```